# How to add column headers in the Column Header band automatically like iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've seen some video tutorials showing that adding fields in the *Detail* band, will automatically add the correspondent column names in the *Column Header* band.

But that doesn't seem to be the same behavior in **Jaspersoft Studio**.

- So how can it be don in **Jaspersoft Studio**?

Also I have some other questions that aren't directly related to the same title:

- How to set the default **Font** for the whole report instead of having to set it to each component **without** using styles?
- **Jaspersoft Studio** is like the new official GUI designer for *JasperReports*, correct? But the old *iReport* designer will still be updated and released alongside?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Question 1. `Jaspersoft Studio is like the new official GUI designer for JasperReports, correct? But the old iReport designer will still be updated and released alongside?`

Yes, the *Jaspersoft Studio* is younger that the *iReport*:

- The [*1.0.0 version of Jaspersoft Studio*](http://sourceforge.net/p/jasperstudio/news/?page=0) was introduced in 2011 July and the [*0.0.3 version*](http://sourceforge.net/p/jasperstudio/news/?page=1) was released at 2010 October.
- The [*0.0.3 version of iReport*](http://sourceforge.net/p/ireport/news/?source=navbar&page=6) was introduced in 2002 October and the [*1.1.0 version*](http://sourceforge.net/p/ireport/news/?source=navbar&page=3) at 2006 February.

*Jaspersoft Studio* is a *Eclipse-based* version and the modern *iReport* is a *NetBeans-based* version of *GUI report designer*. The last version of "classic" standalone *iReport* was [*3.0.0*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ireport/files/iReport%20%28classic%29/).

Сurrently, the latest version for both application is *5.2.0* that support the *JasperReports 5.2.0* framework.

#### Question 2. `How to set the default Font for the whole report instead of having to set it to each component without using styles?`

You can select several *textFields* and set *Font* property at *Text Field* tab like at the image below

[image]

#### Question 3. `So how can it be done in Jaspersoft Studio?`

It can't be done automatically during editing existing report. But you can create report based on one of severals templates, with help of *New Report Wizard*. In this case the *textField* and *staticText* elements will be added automatically to the *Column Header* and *Detail* bands:

[image]

When you edit the existing template you can select several fields and use *drag & drop* feature to add this fields to the band, for example to the *Column Header* band.

[image]

Comment: By using a template to automatically add fields. Do you mean to create a template with preset fields of a specific query ? Because this wouldn't differ much from adding the fields manually for my reports.

Comment: `Do you mean to create a template with preset fields of a specific query ?` - Yes, you choose create a report with help of some of templates (from wizard). You should add query and define fields and only in this case the *iReport's* wizard will add fields automatically to bands.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I've just add some info to my answer